# Can't add exploded data in mysql database with pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I want to insert in my database exploded data using pandas but I get an error, can someone help

**My Code**

```
tactic_theme = pandas.read_csv(link, usecols=(0, 7))
tactic_theme.columns = ['code_tac', 'code_th']

tactic_theme['code_th'] = tactic_theme.code_th.str.split(" ")
tactic_theme.explode('code_th')

tactic_theme.to_sql('tactic_themes', con = engine, if_exists='replace',index=False,chunksize = 1000)
```

**The error**

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1241,
> 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)') [SQL: INSERT INTO tactic_themes
> (code_tac, code_th) VALUES (%(code_tac)s, %(code_th)s)] [parameters:
> ({'code_tac': '0000D', 'code_th': ['advantage', 'endgame', 'short']},
> {'code_tac': '0009B', 'code_th': ['advantage', 'middlegame',
> 'short']}, {'code_tac': '000Vc', 'code_th': ['crushing', 'endgame',
> 'long', 'pawnEndgame']}, {'code_tac': '000Zo', 'code_th': ['endgame',
> 'mate', 'mateIn2', 'short']}, {'code_tac': '000aY', 'code_th':
> ['advantage', 'master', 'middlegame', 'short']}, {'code_tac': '000hf',
> 'code_th': ['mate', 'mateIn2', 'middlegame', 'short']}, {'code_tac':
> '000mr', 'code_th': ['crushing', 'middlegame', 'short']}, {'code_tac':
> '000rO', 'code_th': ['crushing', 'endgame', 'fork', 'short']}  ...
> displaying 10 of 1000 total bound parameter sets ...  {'code_tac':
> '01HAq', 'code_th': ['advantage', 'opening', 'short']}, {'code_tac':
> '01HV2', 'code_th': ['mate', 'mateIn1', 'middlegame', 'oneMove']})]

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the error,on the line `tactic_theme.explode('code_th')` i should write

```
tactic_theme = tactic_theme.explode('code_th')
```